# Shouldn't this CSS3 transition being rotating?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm attempting to make a pie chart that rotates to a certain position then stops when it reaches a certain spot (say 310 degrees or so, doesn't matter).  I've searched Google first like a good boy and came across a great tutorial in CSS-Tricks, as well as several other examples in the comments.  My problem is that when I post the exact same code, literally copy and paste, it doesn't work.

Here is the CSS-Tricks version in action:

http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo

Here is my version doing nothing:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xtbDo

What's the deal?  The thread for the posting has since been closed so I turn to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CodePen click the gear next to CSS and flip it to SCSS and enable prefix free.